# buttons in stackpanel do not stretch with Windows Store app

Tags: wpf, xaml, layout, windows-store-apps

When I tried a simple stackpanel with 2 buttons in a Windows Store project:

```
<Page ...>
    <StackPanel>
        <Button>Button 1</Button>
        <Button>Button 2</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Page>
```

The buttons do not stretch to fill the horizontal space, whereas with the same code in a WPF project, they do stretch:

```
<Window ...>
    <StackPanel>
        <Button>Button 1</Button>
        <Button>Button 2</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

IS there any difference in the way the stackpanel behave? Or is there a difference in general with the layout system between WPF and Metro app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a difference in the default style for the `Button` control.

In WPF, the default style for the `Button` control (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms753328.aspx) does not contain a setter for `HorizontalAlignment`, so WPF `Button`s have the default value, `Stretch`.

However, in a Windows 8  app, the default style for a `Button` explicitly sets the `HorizontalAlignment` to `Left`.  I don't know if this default style is anywhere on MSDN, but, using Blend, I have verified that the `Button`'s default style contains the following setter:

```
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
```

Of course, if you want the Windows 8 buttons to fill the horizontal space, you can always write

```
    <Button HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">Button 1</Button>
    <Button HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">Button 2</Button>
```